# OpenCV 2.4.13 cascade classifier training problems

Tags: c++, opencv, haar-classifier

I tried to train  the haar cascade using the following:

```
C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\opencv_traincascade.exe -data C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\LETTER_TRAIN -vec C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\LETTER.vec -bg C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\LETTER_NEG.dat -numPos 4 -numNeg 28 -numStages 15 -minHitRate 0.995 -w 50 -h 50 -featureType LBP -precalcValBufSize 1024 -precalcldxBufSize 1024
```

When I send this in the Command Prompt, I get:

```
 PARAMETERS:
cascadeDirName: C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\LETTER_TRAIN
vecFileName: C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\LETTERS.vec
bgFileName: C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\LETTER_NEG.dat
numPos: 13
numNeg: 28
numStages: 2
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 1024
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 1024
acceptanceRatioBreakValue : -1
stageType: BOOST
featureType: LBP
sampleWidth: 50
sampleHeight: 50
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.995
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100
Number of unique features given windowSize [50,50] : 166464

===== TRAINING 0-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   13 : 13
Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled. Branch training terminated.
Cascade classifier can't be trained. Check the used training parameters.
```

I tried to solve the problem using [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/10872/cascade-training-error-opencv-244-train-dataset-for-temp-stage-can-not-filled-branch-training-terminated-cascade-classifier-cant-be-trained-check-the/) but it did't help.

The negative images file (.dat) is:

```
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled2.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled3.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled4.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled5.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled6.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled7.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled8.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled9.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled10.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled11.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled12.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled13.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled14.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled15.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled16.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled17.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled18.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled19.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled20.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled21.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled22.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled23.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled24.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled25.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled26.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled27.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled28.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled29.jpg
\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\Untitled30.jpg
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have problems with spaces in filenames (Untitled (2).jpg), but I get different error messages then...

Comment: Thank you for answering, after modifying this line in files I still get the same error  - Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled. Branch training terminated.
Cascade classifier can't be trained. Check the used training parameters.

Comment: I even tried: C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\opencv_traincascade.exe -data C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\LETTER_TRAIN -vec C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\LETTER.vec -bg C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\LETTER_NEG.dat -numPos 4 -numNeg 28 -numStages 15 -minHitRate 0.995 -w 50 -h 50 -featureType LBP -precalcValBufSize 1024 -precalcldxBufSize 1024 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.9801 -maxDepth 1 -mode ALL but it didn't help

Comment: Is the folder LETTER_TRAIN already existing (it must exist!)? Can you try to change all \ to / in the command line (not inside the files)?

Comment: Thank you for helping, the folder LETTER_TRAIN already exists, I tried to change all the \ to / and it still didn't work.

Comment: numPos must be >= 10. See http://answers.opencv.org/question/24136/traincascade-cascade-classifier-cant-be-trained-check-the-used-training-parameters/ (found by googling the error message)

Comment: That's a huge problem for me, I want to train the cascade classifier to detect a single letter so I don't have a minimum of 10 images. Is there something you can suggest me?

Comment: you can add the same images with some additional noise, or perspectively distorted versions of that letter.

Comment: I added more images so now I have 15 positive images and 30 negative, but, I still get the same error as described in the question

Comment: Does it compute anything before the error is generated? Probably there just aren't enough samples for more than x stages. Or reduce the minHitRate. See http://answers.opencv.org/question/58168/traincascade-train-dataset-for-temp-stage-can-not/

Comment: I changed the -numStages to 2 and lowered the -minHitRate and -maxFalseAlarmRate it still doesn't work and has the same error

Comment: is it `LETTER_NEG.dat` or `LETTER_NEG.txt`?  in your question you use name both

Comment: You're right I changed it

Comment: did you try using haar instead of LBP and remove all not needed parameters? And use some really weak values, like `C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\opencv_traincascade.exe -data C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\LETTER_TRAIN -vec C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\LETTER.vec -bg C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\LETTER_NEG.dat -numPos 10 -numNeg 28 -numStages 2 -minHitRate 0.1 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.9999 -w 50 -h 50`

Comment: I did what you suggested me, but, I still get the same error

Comment: can you add your training images, the .vec file and the LETTER_NEG.dat?

Comment: please check this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxebgapvybQuRzJCTFgtQ2VjYnM

Comment: remove the `backslashes` at the beginning of your `LETTER_NEG.dat` you want to access the subfolder relative to your path, should be `LETTERS_NEG(bg)\filename` not `\LETTERS_NEG(bg)\filename`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, just to mention you, I'm using this parameters: \opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\opencv_traincascade.exe -data C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\LETTER_TRAIN -vec C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\LETTERS.vec -bg C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\LETTER_NEG.dat -numPos 14 -numNeg 28 -numStages 2 -minHitRate 0.1 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.9999 -w 50 -h 50

Comment: for me it works, in which folder do you execute that command? The LETTERS_NEG(bg) folder must be a subfolder of your working directory

Comment: OK I got it, I'm new to these things so that might sound silly, I just had to write "cd C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin" in the command prompt, thank you for your time, I appriciate it so much!